# Moving with keyboard (left and right) in flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, keyboard-events

I am trying to move my Avatar left and right in my game as well as stay within the boundaries of the stage (700X500), I am recieving an error stating that the "public attribute can only be used inside the package" am I placing the public functions in the wrong spot?

```
   package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;
    public class SpaceVigilanteGame extends MovieClip

    {
        public var enemy:Enemy;
        public var avatar:Avatar;
        public var gameTimer:Timer;
        public var useMouseControl:Boolean; 
        public var rightKeyIsBeingPressed:Boolean;
        public var leftKeyIsBeingPressed:Boolean; 
        var gameWidth:int = 0;
        var gameHeight:int = 0;

        public function SpaceVigilanteGame()
        {   useMouseControl = false;
            leftKeyIsBeingPressed = false;
            rightKeyIsBeingPressed = false;
            enemy = new Enemy();
            addChild( enemy );
            avatar = new Avatar();
            addChild( avatar );

            if ( useMouseControl )
            {
                avatar.x = mouseX;
                avatar.y = mouseY;
            }
            else
            {
                avatar.x = 50;
                avatar.y = 400;
            }

            gameWidth = stage.stageWidth;
            gameHeight = stage.stageHeight;


            gameTimer = new Timer( 25 );
            gameTimer.addEventListener( TimerEvent.TIMER, moveEnemy );
            gameTimer.addEventListener( TimerEvent.TIMER, moveAvatar );
            gameTimer.start();
            stage.addEventListener( KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyPress );
            stage.addEventListener( KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyRelease );

        public function onKeyPress( keyboardEvent:KeyboardEvent ):void
        {
            if ( keyboardEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT )
            {
                rightKeyIsBeingPressed = true;
            }
        }
        public function onKeyRelease( keyboardEvent:KeyboardEvent ):void
        {
            if ( keyboardEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT )
            {
                rightKeyIsBeingPressed = false;
            }
        }
        }
        public function moveEnemy( timerEvent:TimerEvent ):void 
        {
            //enemy.moveDownABit();
            if(enemy.x+enemy.width+2<=gameWidth)
                {
                    enemy.moveRight();
                }
            else if(enemy.y+enemy.height+2<=gameHeight)
                {
                    enemy.moveDown();
                }
            else if(enemy.x-2>=0)
                {
                    enemy.moveLeft();
                }
            else if(enemy.y-2>=0)
                {
                    enemy.moveUp();
                }

        }
        public function moveAvatar( timerEvent:TimerEvent ):void
        {
            if ( useMouseControl )
            {
                avatar.x = mouseX;
                avatar.y = mouseY;
            }
            else
            {
                if ( rightKeyIsBeingPressed )
                {
                    avatar.moveRight();
                }
            }
        }



    }
}
```

Avatar Class:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    public class Avatar extends MovieClip 
    {
        public function Avatar() 
        {
            x = 50;
            y = 400;

        }

        public function moveRight()
        {
            x = x + 2; 
        }

        public function moveLeft()
        {
            x = x - 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two functions which are `onKeyPress()` and `onKeyRelease()` defined as `public` inside your `SpaceVigilanteGame()` constructor, that's why you got that error, so to avoid that, you have to remove `public` or, if you want to put them as public, and I don't think so, put them out of the constructor of your class.

Hope that can help.

Comment: Removed the 'public' from the 'onKeyPress' and 'onKeyRelease' but now I have a slew of errors. 
Line 46, Column 42 1119: Access of possibly undefined property KEY_RIGHT through a reference with static type Class.

 Line 47, Column 42 1119: Access of possibly undefined property KEY_LEFT through a reference with static type Class.

1061: Call to a possibly undefined method moveRight through a reference with static type Avatar.

Comment: @Leopold_Stotch But there is not a `KeyboardEvent.KEY_RIGHT` and `KeyboardEvent.KEY_LEFT` events, there is `KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN` and `KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP`, and then you can verify if the key ( pressed or released ) is `Keyboard.RIGHT` or `Keyboard.LEFT`.

Comment: There's only events for up and down?

Comment: @Leopold_Stotch Yes, that's it, take a look [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/KeyboardEvent.html) for more details.